# Deleting a user from a oracle database using php

Tags: php, sql, oracle

When I want to delete an email address that is in my querys table in oracle I keep getting this message. **Record Deleted**

> PHP Notice: Undefined index: EMAIL in
>   c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\MBSEBus\113223785\gaye site
>   re-development\DeleteQuerys.php on line 37.

All the connection strings are correct and identical to other statements which iv needed them for.

```
$EMAIL=$_POST['EMAIL'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM QUERYS_113223785 WHERE EMAIL='$EMAIL'";
```

This is the code I'm using in PHP.
any ideas?

Comment: sorry, what's your problem?

Comment: If your form's input is called `name="email"` that is not the same as `name="EMAIL"` so this `$EMAIL=$_POST['EMAIL'];` may need to changed to `$EMAIL=$_POST['email'];` show more code with your form. PHP and POST variables are case-sensitive.

Comment: what's the output for `echo $EMAIL;` ?

Comment: Ya iv fixed that Fred and it still the same error.

Comment: The error message is VERY descriptive: there's no `"EMAIL"` index in `$_POST`. Check out `var_dump($_POST)` to see what actually got posted.

Comment: Figured it out cheers lads

Comment: What was it? @user3463526

Answer (score 0):

Problem is looking like the input field whose name is `EMAIL`. Check whether name that you are using in input and in `$_POST[]` are the same or not.

Answer (score 0):

check your `$_POST`, it seems that you haven't an EMAIL index here:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

and remember to check for sql injection, you have to validate your input before using it!